# Resolve a promise / perform an asynchronous operation inside of .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, react-context

I've been learning React and having an absolute blast. To practice using hooks and the Context API, I've created a very plain Pokemon application that fetches data from the (very awesome) [PokéAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSw0k.png). The problem I can't seem to solve is how to initialize my context by fetching data from a url that is retrieved from the first fetch for data. This is of course a terrible explanation but my code below clarifies.

I've wrapped an `<App />` component in a `<ContextProvider />` like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import App from './App';
import { ContextProvider } from './Context'

ReactDOM.render(
    <ContextProvider>
        <App />    
    </ContextProvider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then jumping right over to my Context.js file, I'm fetching the data I need when the application first loads:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import fetchSprite from './utils/fetchSprite'
const Context = React.createContext()

function ContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [ allPokemon, setPokemon ] = useState([])
    console.log(allPokemon)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=25")
            const pokemon = await response.json()
            
            /* Do ANOTHER async operation here */

            ))
            setPokemon(pokemon.results)
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{ allPokemon }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export { ContextProvider, Context }
```

After parsing the JSON provided as a response, `pokemon.results` is an array of objects, where each object contains a `name` and `url` property. **I'm trying to make an additional fetch call with the `url` on from each object so I can also store a string containing the link to a PNG image.** Again, showing this in the code will make more sense:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import fetchSprite from './utils/fetchSprite'
const Context = React.createContext()

function ContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [ allPokemon, setPokemon ] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=25")
            const pokemon = await response.json()
            const pokeData = pokemon.results.map(obj => (
                {
                    ...obj,
                    sprite: fetchSprite(obj.url)
                }
            ))
            setPokemon(pokeData)
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{allPokemon}}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export { ContextProvider, Context }
```

Above, I'm taking the same array I would pass to `setPokemon`, and essentially copying the array but each object in the array has an additional property `sprite`.

My `fetchSprite.js` file looks like this:

```
async function fetchSprite(url) {
    const res = await fetch(url)
    const data = await res.json()
    const result = data.sprites.front_default
    return result
}

export default fetchSprite
```

I can't figure out how to resolve the Promise being returned by my `fetchSprite` function *inside* of my call to `.map()`. When the array is logged to the console, I have a fulfilled Promise, but can't figure out how to access the result:

[Screenshot of array with fulfilled promises, logged to the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSw0k.png)

How can I essentially have my `.map()` function wait for each promise to resolve before returning the object that's added to the array? I've tried all types of async combinations, like making the anonymous function inside of `.map()` an async function and use await for the `sprite` property. The resulting problem in the UI is the img tags I have reading the PNG url are broken. This has been killing me -- any and all help is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: const pokeData = await Promise.all(pokemon.results.map(....))

Comment: I still wind up with an array of objects, where the `sprite` property on each object is `Promise {<fulfilled>: "...somePokemon.png"} `  :(

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Huzzah!!! Using both `await Promise.all(...)` and making my anonymous function inside of `map` an async function worked. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to [post your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not as an edit to the question.

Comment: @Bergi thanks pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [see sharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284760/see-sharper) for pointing me to [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)!

The entire `map` operation should be wrapped in `await Promise.all()`, *and* the anonymous function inside of map should be an `async` function:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=25")
            const pokemon = await response.json()
            const pokeData = await Promise.all(pokemon.results.map(async (obj) => {
                return {
                    ...obj,
                    sprite: await fetchSprite(obj.url)
                }
            }))
            setPokemon(pokeData)
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])
```